# .Net Core [Authorize] - Or instead of And for permission test

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

The following code authorize filter passes if the user is BOTH a `Role` of "admin" `AND` a `Policy` of "New York".  How do i change it to "admin" `OR` "New York"

```
[Authorize(Policy = "New York", Roles = "admin")]
```

I want an `OR` statement in this specific case, not an `AND`.

Comment: You could write custom Attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in functions to to do that.

But you could easily implement a custom `LogicalOrPolicyProvider` (& also a handler) to achieve the same goal. The `LogicalOrPolicyProvider` will construct policy dynamically according to the policy name, for example:

```
[Authorize(Policy="Choice: policy='New York'| role= ADMIN")]
```

The above attribute will generate a new policy that should fulfill a policy of 'New York' or requires a role of `ADMIN`

Further more, we could define some rules to handle more generic cases. Let's say want to compose the following requirements :

```
Choice: policy='New York'| role= ADMIN
Choice: policy='New York'| role= 'ADMIN'
Choice: policy='New York'| policy = 'WC' | role= root | role = 'GVN'
```

You could define you own rules as you like, I personally prefer to :

1. Start with the token `Choice` followed by separator `:`(May has several optional space chars `' '`)
2. A policy is defined by `policy=policyName`, if the policyName contains space, you should surround it with `''`. You could define many `policy` as you like
3. The role is defined by `role = roleName`. You could also define as many roles as you like.
4. All `policy` & `role` definitions are separated by `|`.

---

#### An Implementation for The above Design:

Let's define a `LogicalOrRequirement` to hold all possible policies:

```
public class LogicalOrRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public IList<AuthorizationPolicy> Policies { get; }

    public LogicalOrRequirement(IList<AuthorizationPolicy> policies)
    {
        this.Policies = policies;
    }
}
```

If any of these polices succeeds, just pass by:

```
public class LogicalOrAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<LogicalOrRequirement>
{

    public LogicalOrAuthorizationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, LogicalOrRequirement requirement)
    {
        var httpContext = this._httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        var policyEvaluator = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IPolicyEvaluator>();
        foreach (var policy in requirement.Policies)
        {
            var authenticateResult = await policyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(policy, httpContext);
            if (authenticateResult.Succeeded)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's build the policy dynamically by `PolicyProvider`:

```
public class LogicalOrPolicyProvider : IAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{
    const string POLICY_PREFIX = "Choice";
    const string TOKEN_POLICY="policy";
    const string TOKEN_ROLE="role";
    public const string Format = "Choice: policy='p3' | policy='p2' | role='role1' | ..."; 

    private AuthorizationOptions _authZOpts { get; }
    public DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider FallbackPolicyProvider { get; }

    public LogicalOrPolicyProvider(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options )
    {
        _authZOpts = options.Value;
        FallbackPolicyProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider(options);
    }


    // Choice: policy= | policy= | role= | role = ...
    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        if (policyName.StartsWith(POLICY_PREFIX, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {   
            var policyNames = policyName.Substring(POLICY_PREFIX.Length);
            var startIndex = policyNames.IndexOf(":");
            if(startIndex == -1 || startIndex == policyNames.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"invalid syntax, must contains a ':' before tokens. The correct format is {Format}");
            }
            // skip the ":" , and turn it into the following list
            //     [[policy,policyName],[policy,policName],...[role,roleName],...,]
            var list= policyNames.Substring(startIndex+1)
                .Split("|")
                .Select(p => p.Split("=").Select(e => e.Trim().Trim('\'')).ToArray() )
                ;

            // build policy for roleNames
            var rolesPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
            var roleNames =list.Where(arr => arr[0].ToLower() == TOKEN_ROLE)
                .Select(arr => arr[1])
                .ToArray();
            var rolePolicy = rolesPolicyBuilder.RequireRole(roleNames).Build();

            // get policies with all related names
            var polices1= list.Where(arr => arr[0].ToLower() == TOKEN_POLICY);
            var polices=polices1 
                .Select(arr => arr[1])
                .Select(name => this._authZOpts.GetPolicy(name))  // if the policy with the name doesn exit => null
                .Where(p => p != null)                            // filter null policy
                .Append(rolePolicy)
                .ToList();

            var pb= new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
            pb.AddRequirements(new LogicalOrRequirement(polices));
            return Task.FromResult(pb.Build());
        }

        return FallbackPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);
    }

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetDefaultPolicyAsync()
    {
        return FallbackPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync();
    }
}
```

Lastly, don't forget to register the two services in your `Startup.cs` :

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, LogicalOrPolicyProvider>();
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, LogicalOrAuthorizationHandler>();
```

Now, whenever you want to logical `or` composition, just add a `[Authorize(Policy="Choice: ...")]`:

```
[Authorize(Policy="Choice: policy='New York'| role= ADMIN")]
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for.  Seems like this would be an common enough situation that Microsoft would have provided natural arguments.

Now I just need to modify the code provided to work with Microsoft's OpenIdConnect Middleware.